# PineScript Syntax error at input '['. How to solve it?

Tags: arrays, syntax, pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trying to define an array of symbols in PineScript (v5) but it tells me Syntax error at input '['. Any idea what the problem might be? I've seen answers on array declaration with floats, but how do I do it with symbols?

`// Define list of symbols to be used symbolList = ["FX_IDC:EURUSD", "FX_IDC:EURCAD", "FX_IDC:GBPJPY"]`

I tried to remove the '[]' and only seperate with commas, I tried {} and (), tried to remove the "FX_ISC:" part. Also asked ChatGPT without any success.
I just want to assign those symbols to the array.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with that array. Symbols are of type `simple string`.

So, you can create a string array to store those. However, when you do that, those will be of type `series string`. So, if you plan to use them in `request.security()`, you cannot.

```
symbol_arr = array.new_string()
array.push(symbol_arr, "BINANCE:BTCBUSD")
array.push(symbol_arr, "BINANCE:ETHBUSD")

btc_close = request.security(array.get(symbol_arr, 0), timeframe.period, close)  // Compiler error
eth_close = request.security(array.get(symbol_arr, 1), timeframe.period, close)  // Compiler error
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I do intend to do that. Is there a work around? Like casting it as a security or something?